# Android Studio Setup Proxy Issue

Tags: android, android-studio

When I trying to install the Android Studio 1.3.1, After Install the Setup it does not open the App It showing the following Image, I was tried to configure my Proxy settings, But it does not accept my credential, I don't know why it happens, Please help to fix this problem.

[image: Android Studio Proxy Issue]

[image: Proxy Forbidden]

[image: Proxy Tunnel Connection Forbidden]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally i found the solution, I was tried above answers, but there is no possibilities to resolve the issue, and lookup the proxy server configuration with the help of network admin, they block this link **https://dl.google.com/android/...**,after grant the permission for the link, now I extracted the Android setup package. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just click and check auto detect and automatic configuration url that's it